# How to generate a proof for a Cairo program and verify it?

Tags: rollups

In SNARKs, you can use [Zokrates](https://zokrates.github.io/gettingstarted.html#hello-zokrates) or [snarkjs](https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs) to generate a proof for a program/computation and verify it, locally or on Ethereum.

Similar to [this unanswered question](https://github.com/starkware-libs/cairo-lang/issues/2), how to do the same in Cairo and STARK for, say, [the 15-puzzle](https://www.cairo-lang.org/docs/hello_cairo/puzzle.html)?

Can `cairo-run` generate a proof, or only a trace?

I can send it to [SHARP](https://www.cairo-lang.org/docs/sharp.html) with `cairo-sharp`, but I can't generate nor see the proof locally. Any way to generate the proof by running my own prover without SHARP?